# Get the product of lists inside a dict while retaining the same keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, product

I have the following dict:

`my_dict = {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1, 4]}`

And I want to end up with a list of dicts like this:

```
[
    {'A': 1, 'B': 1},
    {'A': 1, 'B': 4},
    {'A': 2, 'B': 1},
    {'A': 2, 'B': 4}
]
```

So, I'm after the product of dict's lists, expressed as a list of dicts using the same keys as the incoming dict.

The closest I got was:

```
my_dict = {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1, 4]}
it = []
for k in my_dict.keys():
    current = my_dict.pop(k)
    for i in current:
        it.append({k2: i2 for k2, i2 in my_dict.iteritems()})
        it[-1].update({k: i})
```

Which, apart from looking hideous, doesn't give me what I want:

```
[
    {'A': 1, 'B': [1, 4]}, 
    {'A': 2, 'B': [1, 4]}, 
    {'B': 1}, 
    {'B': 4}
]
```

If anyone feels like solving a riddle, I'd love to see how you'd approach it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this, i.e calculate cartesian product of the value and then simply zip each of the them with the keys from the dictionary. Note that [ordering of a dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)'s `keys()` and corresponding `values()` remains same if it is not modified in-between hence ordering won't be an issue here:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> my_dict = {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1, 4]}
>>> keys = list(my_dict)
>>> [dict(zip(keys, p)) for p in product(*my_dict.values())]
[{'A': 1, 'B': 1}, {'A': 1, 'B': 4}, {'A': 2, 'B': 1}, {'A': 2, 'B': 4}]
```

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I was after. I assumed (should have checked) that keys() and values() taken separately wouldn't remain in sync, that in fact they do is a useful bit of python foo to remember.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function within a list comprehension :

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [dict(i) for i in product(*[[(i,k) for k in j] for i,j in my_dict.items()])]
[{'A': 1, 'B': 1}, {'A': 1, 'B': 4}, {'A': 2, 'B': 1}, {'A': 2, 'B': 4}]
```

You can get the pairs contain your key and values with the following list comprehension :

```
[(i,k) for k in j] for i,j in my_dict.items()]
[[('A', 1), ('A', 2)], [('B', 1), ('B', 4)]]
```

Then you can use `product` to calculate the product of the preceding lists and then convert them to dictionary with `dict` function.

Answer (score 1):

With itertools:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> my_dict = {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1, 4]}
>>> keys, items = zip(*my_dict.items())
>>> [dict(zip(keys, x)) for x in product(*items)]
[{'A': 1, 'B': 1}, {'A': 1, 'B': 4}, {'A': 2, 'B': 1}, {'A': 2, 'B': 4}]
```

Comment: I like this solution, it's slightly more readable than Ashwini's imo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from itertools import product

def dict_product(values, first, second):
   return [
       {first: first_value, second: second_value}
       for first_value, second_value in product(values[first], values[second])
   ]
```

This is the result:

```
>>> dict_product({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1, 4]}, 'A', 'B')
[{'A': 1, 'B': 1}, {'A': 1, 'B': 4}, {'A': 2, 'B': 1}, {'A': 2, 'B': 4}]
```